# "How are" or "What are" question

Tags: word-choice, questions

I have the following text in my mobile app:

**How are the marked rows called?**

The app has been published for several years, and today I received an email from one of the users:

> Just wanted to let you know that, “How are the marked diagonals called?” Is not proper English and sounds really weird to native speakers. It should be, “What are the marked diagonals called?”

Why the "how" should be changed to "what"? I thought "How are ... **called**" is the right choice, because the question asks about **how** they are called, not **what** they are.

Comment: To use an example, are they called *loudly* (the manner in which they are called) or are they called *XYZ* (the name by which they are called)?

Comment: In what way can we describe _how_ the diagonals are called in the context of your example?

Comment: The question asks for a term. A special term used to call such diagonals.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev No it doesn't. The OP's question asks if it's OK to use "what" in their cited example, when "how" would seem more appropriate.

Comment: @BillJ. Sorry. I mean "How are the marked rows called?" asks for a term.

Comment: "What are they called" is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=What+are+they+called%2CHow+are+they+called&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20are%20they%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHow%20are%20they%20called%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CWhat%20are%20they%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHow%20are%20they%20called%3B%2Cc0) than "How are they called"

Comment: @Henry much thanks for the link!

Comment: "They are called A, B and Caeruleaniphrous."  ... "A, B and _**what**_?"

Comment: **1** What is a pronoun = which thing/noun/gerund, NP, etc. The answer requires a substantive:  ”What (which noun) is that?” “It is a dog.” **2** How is an adverb = in which style/method. The answer requires an adverb. Q: “How do you do that?” A: “I do it carefully/ by filling the glass/ from the tap.” *Carefully*, and *by filling the glass/ from the tap.* are both adjuncts (adverbial modifiers.)

Comment: This is a common quirk in Indian English and likely some other dialects.  It sounds wrong to American and likely British ears, but is generally understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How" and "What", in my opinion, are very different question words in such a phrase like "How/what is it called?". Whereas "what" refers to the description or the terminology behind the word, "how" refers to the manner or style of calling it.

Examples:

- How is the dog called? - "Come here dog!"
- What is the dog called? - "Mopsy"

Answer (score 1):

If the app question is asking for the name of the row, *what* is correct because it refers to and requests the row name. *How* would refer adverbially to the manner of naming (=calling).

A little more context might help. An app, being a piece of computer code, may work by calling procedures as required. If the app question were asking about programming procedures somehow associated with the rows in the app, *how* would be appropriate to the calling of them in this sense.